# Why the value is changed for the Read-Only Compound Literal?

Tags: c, constants, compound-literals

I was studying the Read-Only compound literals in C. And when I tried to change its value with the help of dereference operator, the value got changed!!
I am now confused why is that so.

Also when I compiled and run the program (Without attempting to change its value) it shows this error:

```
Code_Testing.c:5:14: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    5 |     int *r = (const int[3]){6, 14, -98}; // Read Only compound Literal
      |
```

I cannot  understand why it is ignoring the `const` qualifier.

I know that `const` qualifier discards any change, but here the value of the compound literal changed!

Can you please explain me where I had committed a mistake?

The program I wrote is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *r = (const int[3]){6, 14, -98}; // Read Only compound Literal
    *r += 99;
    printf("The changed value is = %d", *r);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Code_Testing.c:5:14: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    5 |     int *r = (const int[3]){6, 14, -98}; // Read Only compound Literal
      |              ^
The changed value is = 105
```

Comment: *I know that `const` qualifier discards any change*  Not when you throw it away by assignment or explicit casting.  `const` in C is very weak - it wasn't even part of the language for quite some time.

Comment: What do you mean by “Read-Only compound literals”? Compound literals are not read-only in general, although they are if you define them with `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign the `const int[]` array to a pointer to a non-`const` value. This means **you** as the programmer explicitly discard the `const` qualifyer. (The `const` on the right side actually does declare the literal as `const`.)

The compiler warns you about this.

To fix the warning you would have to use

```
const int *r = (const int[3]){6, 14, -98}; // Read Only compound Literal
```

Then you would get an error at the line

```
*r += 99;
```

where you want to modify the value.

The `const` qualifyer doesn't "discard any changes". As you can see, there are ways to modify the value. (But this is undefined behavior.)
The `const` qualifyer tells the compiler that the value should not be modified, and the compiler will show errors or warnings when your code would modify it or when it detects a use that could lead to modification of a value of `const` type.

Comment: Thanks, actually I thought that adding `const` to right hand side will automatically made the literal a constant. Thanks for clearing my doubt :-)

Comment: What do you mean the literal should be `const` anyway? C permits modifying compound literals.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to modify the value of a const-qualified object with an lvalue of non-const-qualified type, it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.7.3

> *If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. [...]*

The assignment here discards the const-qualifier from the initializer, and assigns that to a non-const-qualified lvalue, so your compiler tried to warn you about the potential pitfall.